# PHP array selection not working correctly

Tags: php

I am working on a website that alternates section depending on the ID, I created this code but noticed one of my parameters is not working correctly

```
$fb_prac = array('34565', '34565', '1212', '1192', '1219', '1180', '1234','1186', '1221'); 
if (get_the_ID() != ('34565' or '34565' or '1212' or '1192' or '1219' or '1180' or '1234' or '1221')) {
    include 'facebook.html';}
    else {
        if (get_the_ID() == '1186') {
         include 'facebook-1186.html';}else{
    echo do_shortcode('[facebook_card]');}}
```

The ID pointing to 1186 is ok and the else echoing the shot code is ok BUT the array wit the IDs pointing to facebook.html do not load. Is there something wrong with my syntax? Any help is appreciated

Comment: this is not javascript

Comment: `$fb_prac`? Are you writing php in JS?

Comment: This looks like Wordpress.  (`do_shortcode` is a Wordpress function, AFAIK).  Regardless, this definitely isn't JS.

Comment: im sorry I meant to put PHP!

Comment: That `if` line with these `or` conditions does not look like valid PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to use the `in_array` function?

```
if (in_array(get_the_ID(), $fb_prac)) {
    include 'facebook.html';
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: I did and when I do that it overwrites the else for 1186 and the shortcode else, it just puts the facebook.html globally

Comment: Just compare that ID before this one.

Comment: this doesn't work, the pages that display the shortcode and the 1186 page all show the facebook.html

Comment: @triby not following what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @triby I think I noticed what you mean! 1186 was in the array

Comment: if(get_the_id() == 1186) { /* do something */ } elseif(/* the other if */) { /*do other thing */ }

Comment: @triby Thank you for your help! I removed the 1186 from the top array and now everything is showing where it should! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading the logic like this, if the id matches 1186 include facebook-1186.html, if the id is NOT in your array $fb_prac, then include facebook.html.  Else do the shortcode.

```
<?php

$fb_prac = array('34565', '34565', '1212', '1192', '1219', '1180', '1234','1186', '1221'); 
$id = get_the_ID();

if ($id == '1186') {
    include 'facebook-1186.html';
}
elseif (!in_array($id, $fb_prac)) {
    include 'facebook.html';
}
else {
    echo do_shortcode('[facebook_card]');
}
```